# How to resize an Entry Box by height in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

is there any short method to increase the height of website_entry Tkinter Entry object as in code -

> website_entry = Entry(width=35,bg="#001C30",fg="white")
> website_entry.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=2)
> website_entry.focus()

tried using

```
widget.place(x=int,y=int,width=int,height=int)
```

but it creates error to be created with .grid method

Comment: An Entry widget has no height afaik; use the font size to affect the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to explicitly tell the Entry to increase in height as you have.  The height of the box is dictated by the font size.  You can change the font and font size like this:

```
website_entry = Entry(width=35,bg="#001C30",fg="white", font=('Arial', 40))
```

Note that you can pick any font that you want, it doesn't have to be Arial.
More generally:

```
font=('font_name', font_size)
```